# What would I need To change in this code for the text to be displayed in share sheet?

Tags: swift

I have my text which doesn't display in the debug area it says

"[6384:3178597] plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated"

The code which I have been using is the following:

```
@IBAction func Share(sender: AnyObject) { 
    let firstActivityItem = " Hello "
    let ActivityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil) 
    self.presentViewController(ActivityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```

also if anyone can give me the code to add an image and a link to the action sheet it would also be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this example:

```
class DataToShow{
    var url: String = ""
    var text: String = ""
    var image: UIImage?
}

var myData: DataToShow!

@IBAction func shareButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    let firstActivityItem = myData.text
    let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(string: myData.url)!
    let image : UIImage? = myData.image

    var activities = [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem]
    if image != nil{
        activities.append(image!)
    }

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activities, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros

   //This part is to center it on current UIViewController 
    let x = self.view.center
    activityViewController.view.frame.origin.x = x.x
    activityViewController.view.frame.origin.y = x.y

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(x.x, x.y, 0, 0)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//This is for maintening it centered when changing orientation...
override func popoverPresentationController(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverToRect rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, inView view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView?>) {
    let x = popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.view.center
    var newRect = CGRectMake(x.x , x.y, 0, 0)
    rect.initialize(newRect)
}
```

This has been tested on iPad and iPhone. Centered part of the code is just for iPad, on IPhone it behaves different.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hugo Alonso I do not have any errors left, however I still have nothing that displays when I try to post. Is this the only thing I should be changing ?                                                                                                                                                                                           class DataToShow{
        var url: String = "http://www.facebook.com"
        var text: String = "hello"
        var image: UIImage?

Comment: Hi @StephenDeverell, can you explain a little where and what are you trying to display something when you try to post? ..maybe an screenshot of another app that does what you are trying to do...

Comment: I will try and find an app that does this and post it, but I can't right now, what you told me to do is exactly what I want except that I want pre loaded text, link and image (right now I have the sharing box that opens but is empty) if that makes any sense? @Hugo Alonso

Comment: 1.- Are u testing on a real device? 2.- Data to show, the one in `myData` should be provided by you prior calling this function

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my Xcode crashed and wouldn't work for a bit, any way it's working now so thanks a lot for the help @Hugo Alonso